# Version differences in Parallelize

Tags: parallelization, version-7, version-6

I am having a problem which I guess is due to version difference. I have to generate a list of unitary matrices, which I can do easily. However I came to know about `Parallelize` command by which I wanted to speed the process. First the Hamiltonian (if anybody really wants to check)

```
X = 1/Sqrt[2] {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};
Y = I/Sqrt[2] {{0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}};
Z = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0, -1}];
Subscript[S, 1, x] = KroneckerProduct[X, IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3]];
Subscript[S, 2, x] = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3], X, IdentityMatrix[3]];
Subscript[S, 3, x] = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3], X];
Subscript[S, 1, y] = KroneckerProduct[Y, IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3]];
Subscript[S, 2, y] = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3], Y, IdentityMatrix[3]];
Subscript[S, 3, y] = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3], Y];
Subscript[S, 1, z] = KroneckerProduct[Z, IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3]];
Subscript[S, 2, z] =  KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3], Z, IdentityMatrix[3]];
Subscript[S, 3, z] = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3], Z];
H = Sum[Sum[(Subscript[S, i, x].Subscript[S, j, x] + 
      Subscript[S, i, y].Subscript[S, j, y] + 
      Subscript[S, i, z].Subscript[S, j, z]), {j, i + 1, 3}], {i, 1, 
    3}];
```

Now, the table

```
unitary = ParallelTable[Chop[N[MatrixExp[I θ H]]], {θ, 0, 1, 1/100}]; // Timing
```

The problem is, it is not working in *Mathematica* 7  and gives the following errors:

```
MatrixExp::matsq: Argument 0 at position 1 is not a nonempty square matrix.
```

*Mathematica* 8 gives result without any trouble and error! 
I guess it is due to some version difference. Can someone give me a workaround method for both *Mathematica* 6 and 7? I can only use 6 for any lengthy calculation, and it seems to speed up the calculations a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version 7 I believe you need this before the `ParallelTable` call:

```
DistributeDefinitions[H]
```

For version 6 I don't know, but presumably you will need to define `H` in each kernel manually.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that. this is the first time i am trying to use parallel process. i do not know how many kernels it will take (as some other guys use it for same purpose too).

Comment: @rsg as version 6 doesn't even have `ParallelTable` how are you going about this?

Comment: true. there was a toolkit for 6 by which i hoped i could do some of the things. It seems it is not possible. i have to work in 7 instead. thanks for the help.

Comment: @rsg I'm not sure. I think you should not Accept this answer yet as someone may have a solution if they know to look at the question.

Comment: @rsg just for completeness, the `DistributeDefinitions`-equivalent function in the PCT is called `ExportEnvironment`. However, I don't have version 6 or the PCT installed any more so unfortunately I can't test whether 6 can actually do this calculation correctly as stated.